# Tablenotes are not justified below the table

Tags: resize, tablenotes

Sorry, this could easily be a silly question, but I've been spending hours to figure it out what I am doing wrong and still not have an answer.
I have a very long table, and I would like to put it into one single page, using \resizebox, but whereas the table recognises the command, the notes below don't. How do I put the table notes below the table?
Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass[12pt, italian english]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\hypertarget{table4}{\caption{Main table results, local level}}
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\begin{center}
\resizebox{!}{.35\paperheight}{%
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Local level}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Long table results}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}\\
\hline
A          &      0.0266\sym{**} &      0.0282\sym{**} \\
                    &      (2.01)         &      (2.12)         \\
[1em]
B   &      0.0253\sym{***}&      0.0254\sym{***}\\
                    &      (4.55)         &      (4.55)         \\
[1em]
C            &     -0.0436\sym{*}  &     -0.0419\sym{*}  \\
                &     (-1.94)         &     (-1.85)         \\
[1em]
D           &     -0.0362         &     
-0.0359         \\
                &     (-1.31)         &     (-1.30)         \\
[1em]
E\\
[1em]
E1                &     -0.0784\sym{*}  &         .            \\
                &     (-1.82)         &            .         \\
[1em]
E2               &     -0.0144         &        .             \\
                &     (-0.35)         &           .          \\
[1em]
F\\
[1em]
F1              &     .                &     -0.0766         \\
                &            .         &     (-1.47)         \\
[1em]
F2        &     .                &      -0.125\sym{**} \\
                &      .               &     (-2.34)         \\
[1em]
F3       &        .             &    -0.00966         \\
                &        .             &     (-0.15)         \\
[1em]
F4          &       .              &      -0.158\sym{*}  \\
                &          .           &     (-1.67)         \\
[1em]
F5           &               .      &      -0.117         \\
                &            .         &     (-1.24)         \\
[1em]
F6     &      .               &      -0.118         \\
                &          .           &     (-0.79)         \\
[1em]
F7&         .            &      -0.112         \\
                &          .           &     (-1.58)         \\
[1em]
Constant            &       0.334\sym{**} &       0.391\sym{**} \\
                &      (1.99)         &      (2.26)         \\
[1em]
\textsc{Controls}: & & \\
Population & \textsc{Yes} & \textsc{Yes}\\
Province & \textsc{Yes} & \textsc{Yes}\\
Other controls & \textsc{Yes} &\textsc{Yes}\\
[1em]
\textsc{Ref. Category} & &\\
E:& E3 & .\\
D & D2 & D2\\
F & . & F8\\
\hline
Observations        &         388         &         388         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.1\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}
\begin{tablenotes}
\scriptsize
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse faucibus nunc vitae vulputate aliquet. Nam bibendum dui at sem dapibus, nec tincidunt turpis malesuada. Sed porta, tellus eu hendrerit eleifend, nisi metus maximus nisi, et posuere neque ligula eu neque. Sed nec erat lobortis, auctor magna sit amet, scelerisque augue. Vestibulum placerat blandit elementum. Pellentesque convallis ante vel tincidunt placerat. Phasellus facilisis consectetur rutrum. Mauris gravida purus magna, in vehicula ipsum cursus nec. Nunc rutrum porta dolor, id congue odio consectetur sit amet. Ut pellentesque odio quis mauris maximus, ut tempus felis posuere. Fusce eleifend iaculis nisl, quis pellentesque mauris fermentum id.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello John, I would simply like to justify the notes inside of the table layout.
To be more specific, in my code, notes are displayed as they were simple text, whereas I would like to put them below the table, according to table geometry.
Ask me anything if I wasn't clear. Sorry, this is my first time on the blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution puts the resized tabular inside a dummy tabular which is used to determine the width of the tablenotes.  Since they are already `\scriptsize`, I hope you don't intend to shrink them any more.

```
\documentclass[12pt, italian english]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlength{\tempdima}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\hypertarget{table4}{\caption{Main table results, local level}}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\resizebox{!}{.35\textheight}{\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Local level}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Long table results}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}\\
\hline
A          &      0.0266\sym{**} &      0.0282\sym{**} \\
                    &      (2.01)         &      (2.12)         \\
[1em]
B   &      0.0253\sym{***}&      0.0254\sym{***}\\
                    &      (4.55)         &      (4.55)         \\
[1em]
C            &     -0.0436\sym{*}  &     -0.0419\sym{*}  \\
                &     (-1.94)         &     (-1.85)         \\
[1em]
D           &     -0.0362         &     
-0.0359         \\
                &     (-1.31)         &     (-1.30)         \\
[1em]
E\\
[1em]
E1                &     -0.0784\sym{*}  &         .            \\
                &     (-1.82)         &            .         \\
[1em]
E2               &     -0.0144         &        .             \\
                &     (-0.35)         &           .          \\
[1em]
F\\
[1em]
F1              &     .                &     -0.0766         \\
                &            .         &     (-1.47)         \\
[1em]
F2        &     .                &      -0.125\sym{**} \\
                &      .               &     (-2.34)         \\
[1em]
F3       &        .             &    -0.00966         \\
                &        .             &     (-0.15)         \\
[1em]
F4          &       .              &      -0.158\sym{*}  \\
                &          .           &     (-1.67)         \\
[1em]
F5           &               .      &      -0.117         \\
                &            .         &     (-1.24)         \\
[1em]
F6     &      .               &      -0.118         \\
                &          .           &     (-0.79)         \\
[1em]
F7&         .            &      -0.112         \\
                &          .           &     (-1.58)         \\
[1em]
Constant            &       0.334\sym{**} &       0.391\sym{**} \\
                &      (1.99)         &      (2.26)         \\
[1em]
\textsc{Controls}: & & \\
Population & \textsc{Yes} & \textsc{Yes}\\
Province & \textsc{Yes} & \textsc{Yes}\\
Other controls & \textsc{Yes} &\textsc{Yes}\\
[1em]
\textsc{Ref. Category} & &\\
E:& E3 & .\\
D & D2 & D2\\
F & . & F8\\
\hline
Observations        &         388         &         388         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.1\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\scriptsize
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse faucibus nunc vitae vulputate aliquet. Nam bibendum dui at sem dapibus, nec tincidunt turpis malesuada. Sed porta, tellus eu hendrerit eleifend, nisi metus maximus nisi, et posuere neque ligula eu neque. Sed nec erat lobortis, auctor magna sit amet, scelerisque augue. Vestibulum placerat blandit elementum. Pellentesque convallis ante vel tincidunt placerat. Phasellus facilisis consectetur rutrum. Mauris gravida purus magna, in vehicula ipsum cursus nec. Nunc rutrum porta dolor, id congue odio consectetur sit amet. Ut pellentesque odio quis mauris maximus, ut tempus felis posuere. Fusce eleifend iaculis nisl, quis pellentesque mauris fermentum id.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: John, thank you very much! Your code worked perfectly! Have a nice day! :)